# Google sheets - Multiple smart filter

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I am really new in Google sheets.
I would like to create something simple.
I have a list of hospitals and every week I take note of the number of surgical procedures that are done in each hospital.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y_LYgp4yFIwglTbwtjER4ah_C3tQQ1sVZaUO_Payups/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to create 2 filters:

- Select the hospital
- Select "start week" and "end week"

and visualize the plot referred only to the resulting data coming from the filter.
Is someone able to help me?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B2:N13; B1:N1>=Q2; B1:N1<=Q3); MATCH(Q4; A2:A; 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Is it possible to have a drop down menu to select the week and the hospital? For instance, when I add a week I would like the drop down menu to automatically update to include the last added week. The shared example is simple, but I will have more than 100 weeks. Thanks!